# InsertAsync response from azure

Tags: c#, javascript, http, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have a server script that upon insert procedure, validates if this item.name exists. 
If it does a

```
request.respond(statusCodes.BAD_REQUEST, { error: 'Name Exists' });
```

is send. But on the client site this is not received by the function insertAsync, since this is a void function.

How do I get the response such that I can react to this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the method is void, but returning a BAD REQUEST as you are doing will result in an exception in the client which you need to handle.

Comment: Thanks : I found it out but forgot to write it here :)